# Vscode autocompletion doesn't work for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I recently started using Jupyter Notebooks on vscode but i've notices that code autocompletion doesn't work properly.

If i create a regular .py file everything works correctly as you can see. It shows function signature and docstring. In both core python language and extern modules.

[image: correct autocompletion core]

[image: correct autocompletion extern]

But if i try the same in a .ipynb file it completely ignores autocompletion for print()

[image: incorrect autocompletion]

And what confuses me too if that for example it shows me np.sum() docstring but it doesn't show me any np.concatenate() information gamong any other np.functions or other modules

[[image: autocomplete np.sum4]

[image: autocomplete np.concatenate]

Just in case im using Vscode and an conda enviroment as my python interpreter.
Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
"python.dataScience.jupyterServerURI": "local",
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\myUser\\anaconda3\\envs\\myEnv\\python.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to your description, the reason for this situation is that different language services provide different functions such as automatic completion and prompts.

For the "`print()`" and "`np.concatenate()`" you mentioned, it is recommended that you use the "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)" extension, which provides excellent language services and auto-complete functions.

Please add the following settings in `settings.json`:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

[image]

[image]

Update:

Starting from November 2020, the function of Jupyter notebook in VSCode is provided by the extension "Jupyter", which uses the "IntelliSense" provided by the extension "Jupyter".
And in "VSCode-insider" Jupyter notebook has better "IntelliSense":

[image]

Github link: [Hover Documentation Pop up does not work after VSCode 1.52 update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4218).

Answer (score 3):

This has helped in my case, simply add to `settings.json` the following:

**For Windows**

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe"
    ],
```

**For Linux**

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/usr/bin/python3"
    ],
```

*For more information:*

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing

*For other tips, visit:*

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support